# Drawing projection of geodesic lines with QGIS

Tags: qgis, geodesic

I'm trying to do some visualization for a project using QGIS. I am also open for other open source tools. Essentially I have one NetCDF file that has values for the sea level on a grid and an additional dataset given by a set of geodesic lines on the sphere. Now I want to visualize both on a global map projection, similar to the following figure (which is a figure from another research paper):

[image]

Is QGIS the right tool for the job? If yes, how would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a *problem-solving* site. Complex "is it possible?" Questions are not a a good fit for our Focused question/Best answer model. I suggest you make an attempt, then, if you run into a specific problem, document that exact issue.

Comment: Welcome. As highlighted in the previous comment, please provide more information of what you tried, and yes, QGIS should do the job

Comment: and please don't post the exact same question on both here and stackoverflow